# Erro java.lang.NullPointerException ao enviar dados para um webservice

Tags: java, c#, asp.net-mvc, web-service

tenho um webservice onde estou enviando alguns dados. O retorno do serviço está me retornando esta mensagem a baixo, no manual de integração, diz que seria um erro interno, queria entender se o problema está do meu lado ou do serviço disponibilizado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><Message>
    <MessageId>
        <ServiceId>SolicitaLogon</ServiceId>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
        <MsgDesc>SolicitaÃ§Ã£o do Desafio de Logon</MsgDesc>
        <Code>2052105043</Code>
        <FromAddress>TJ</FromAddress>
        <ToAddress>PGE</ToAddress>
        <Date>2018-06-15</Date>
    </MessageId>
    <MessageBody>
        <Resposta>
            <Mensagem>
                <Codigo>1</Codigo>
                <Descricao>ERRO INTERNO; DETALHES: java.lang.NullPointerException</Descricao>
            </Mensagem>
        </Resposta>
    </MessageBody>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>92QOnSuXAIiWFv7wgwywn6/acNM=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>MNQVELicGB76yNV3cRIPOaTNxr9DgVy498cgWAVkq3V23E1yFGIg2tGjuCDTEPlkUap5QHT/eMHO
s7Ho7eBh1RDn6Tjj5BIvTRNoXexFx/vE/XS9OnSuVUUqCvuH4y0arLcwlk9NZWnBqvuxEubC7a0o
1rh/KytGAdEKzzryY7E=</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>MIICrzCCAhgCCQDVUHUkOXrNMDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBmzELMAkGA1UEBhMCQlIxDzANBgNV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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></Message>
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu cliente está escrito em C#. Logo, não há como ocorrer um `java.lang.NullPointerException` do seu lado. Porque como o nome dessa exceção já diz, é uma exceção do Java.

Pode até ser que você tenha invocado o serviço deles com algum dado ou parâmetro inválido, mas mesmo assim, continua sendo erro deles do mesmo jeito. Em 99% das vezes, ter um `NullPointerException` sendo cuspido para fora é um erro de programação. Nos demais 1% é sinal de que o código é uma gambiarra muito mal-feita sem qualquer tipo de tratamento de erros decente. No caso, o componente de onde veio esse erro é o servidor deles, e portanto é lá que está o erro.